# Background audio task with media element (video) in foreground

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, background-task

I'm facing a problem with a Background Audio Task in my universal app.

My problem consists in this scenario:

- I suspend my app and launch a sound in my Background Audio Task;
- I resume my app, and my first screen is a video;
- My Background task is cancelled with SystemPolicy reason.

I think it is related with the audio from the video and the audio from the background task..they enter in conflict and the BG is cancelled.

Is there anyway to avoid this? Or any workaround?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want the background audio to play along with the video or can you afford to pause the sound while the video plays? If the latter is the case then you can save the position of the current track to your local application settings in the task cancelled event handler and as soon as your video ends you can relaunch your task and resume the track from the same point.

Comment: What I can do is pause the video when the audio starts...it's a kind of alarm so everything can pause less the audio

Comment: That shouldn't be too hard then. Whenever your alarm triggers, check if the background task is running, if it is, just send a message to the background to play your sound and if it's not, stop the video (if it's playing), and attempt to relaunch the background task. The latter will incur a slight delay though.